Stop Chrome from automatic reset when setting up new mac
When transferring data to new mac, regardless of manual copy or restore from time machine backup, when opening chrome on the new mac chrome automatically resets itself. It means that extension data and cookies are gone and is generally a lot of other hassle. I will need to do this a couple of times soon. Is there any way to trick Chrome to believe that it is still on the same OS or disable this resetting behavior?
From some experiments I think it at least detects:

Changes in hardware; using same bootable drive in different intel macs results in this behavior everytime I use it on a new mac
Changes in system configuration: after my mac is repaired (new logic board has same serial number), I had to recover the system from backup, and this happens

